# htaccess and POST variable issues with Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

So I am doing a bit of research on this topic, and you would think there would be an answer but there isn't, or maybe I am looking in the wrong area.

**Problem**

When submitting a form my post variables are empty. I am passing them through properly, the form goes where it needs to go to, and the variables and form data appear properly and with values, in the headers. I have the form helper autoloaded in the config, so everything is how it should be.

my form opener looks like this:

```
<form action='/Forms/form_processor/' method='post' id='testForm'>
```

In my `Forms` controller looks like this:

```
define('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Forms extends CI_Controller{
    public function form_processor(){
        // get variables
        $name = $this->input->post('name');

        // ... do stuff with variable data
    }
}
```

I would also note that with the use of the htaccess file my config variables are:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = ''; // this is to keep index.php out of the URL
```

**Possible Cause**

When using codeigniter and sitting at the home page, you get this URL:

```
http://example.com
```

That is fine, until you go to the next page, you get this URL:

```
http://example.com/index.php/page
```

It looks ugly, so for aesthetic purposes and to keep uniformity I created an htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /example.com/
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
</IfModule>
```

and then by having this htaccess file at the base directory I get the URL to look like this:

```
http://example.com/page
```

**Temp Fix and Questions Needing Answers**

It was pointed out to me that because my `$config['index_page']` variable is null that this is where the problems are stemming from. So I added the `index.php` to the beginning of my url in the form's action and it goes through.

Shouldn't the htaccess re-write handle this issue, and send it to where it is supposed to go where I have the `index.php` in the form's action URL or not?

Secondly, how would this affect the post variables? Because when I submit the form it still gets to where it needs to go to, it just shows null for all the variables, even though they are properly sent through the headers. This is where I am most confused.

If you need more information please let me know, but we are just trying to figure out why this is happening over here, it's kind of awkward. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems complicated. I think there might be an issue with installation steps. Remove index.php from config, set base url (also in application/config.php), set the encryption key(also there).

Check what are the session settings - did you change something there.

Also simplify htaccess (put it where is your index.php)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Is this local or server issue?

And last - try to use form helper, does it change something, whats inside console? Show more of your controller. You can check post inside one function

```
class Forms extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function form_processor()
    {
        //check if $_POST
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $name=$this->input->post('name');
            //process and redirect
        }

        $this->load->view('forms/my_form');
    }
}
```

Also if you use xss_filtering or csrf_protection(check that in config.php) you should definitely use form helper.

Comment: can you possibly show samples of the set up steps that you mentioned above?

Comment: 1. Download CI installation files, 2. Extract to web root, 3. Open application/config/config.php, 3. Add $config['base_url'], erase index.php from $config['index_page'], add encryption key down in the same file. 4. Create .htaccess inside directory, where index.php lies.

Comment: Once I remember I had problem because of naming my input name name="name" but don't exactly remember what was the issue, now I don't have such problems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845482/post-variables-not-sending-php-apache-codeigniter

Comment: so you havent got mod rewrite enabled in your server?

Comment: I didn't but I do now

Answer (score -1):

/forms/form_processor/' method='post' id='testForm'>

Use base URL in form action.
If not work so use index.php after base URL.

Comment: This is already a known issue. I've explained this in my question.

Comment: You not use method in form. You use action="post".